# How to give the input for the kubectl command?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

Actually I am trying to make the following command in one command

```
kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+'

output
mag121111
```

After that I will run the following command

```
kubectl exec -itmag121111 bash
```

Now I am trying as following

```
 kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+' | kubectl exec -it bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+') --/bin/bash
```

OR

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+') --bash
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works exactly , but if not , try -- before /bin/bash

Comment: Also if there are multiple containers in a pod , you need to specify the container id as well

Answer (score 1):

> kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+') -- /bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kube-fzf](https://github.com/thecasualcoder/kube-fzf). It makes `exec into a pod(container)` and `portforward` super **easy**.

Refer [this](https://github.com/thecasualcoder/kube-fzf#execpod-1) for execpod

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods| grep -oP 'mag[^\s]+') --container magname -- /bin/bash
```

here magname is actual pod name